# Select rows where column value has changed

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, select

Let's say I have the following table:

```
Value    Time
0        15/06/2012 8:03:43 PM
1        15/06/2012 8:03:43 PM     *
1        15/06/2012 8:03:48 PM 
1        15/06/2012 8:03:53 PM
1        15/06/2012 8:03:58 PM     
2        15/06/2012 8:04:03 PM     *
2        15/06/2012 8:04:08 PM
3        15/06/2012 8:04:13 PM     *
3        15/06/2012 8:04:18 PM
3        15/06/2012 8:04:23 PM
2        15/06/2012 8:04:28 PM     *
2        15/06/2012 8:04:33 PM
```

How do I select the starred rows, that is, where `Value` has changed?  Basically I'm trying to find the time when `Value` has changed so I can do other queries based on those time intervals.  The solution shouldn't depend on knowing `Value` or `Time` in advance.

It seems to me that this shouldn't be very hard (but it's hard enough for me apparently!).

I'm currently using SQL Server 2008 although I have access to 2012 if the new window/analytic functions are helpful.

I tried adapting the solutions here http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/11/24/sql-server-solution-to-puzzle-simulate-lead-and-lag-without-using-sql-server-2012-analytic-function/ but my query didn't complete after an hour!  I think the joins explode the row size to something unmanageable (or I screwed it up).

I can solve this problem with C# code and multiple db calls, but it seems like something that could be done in a table-valued function or SP which would be much nicer.

Also, a solution that only works with increasing `Value` is OK if that is easier.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I think this is what you're after:

```
;WITH x AS
(
  SELECT value, time, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
  (PARTITION BY Value ORDER BY Time)
  FROM dbo.table
)
SELECT * FROM x WHERE rn = 1;
```

This may be slow if the resultset is large and there isn't a good supporting index...

**EDIT**

Ah, wait a second, the values go up and down, not just up... if that is the case you can try this much slower approach:

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(value INT, [time] DATETIME)

INSERT @x VALUES
(0,'20120615 8:03:43 PM'),--
(1,'20120615 8:03:43 PM'),--*
(1,'20120615 8:03:48 PM'),--
(1,'20120615 8:03:53 PM'),--
(1,'20120615 8:03:58 PM'),--
(2,'20120615 8:04:03 PM'),--*
(2,'20120615 8:04:08 PM'),--
(3,'20120615 8:04:13 PM'),--*
(3,'20120615 8:04:18 PM'),--
(3,'20120615 8:04:23 PM'),--
(2,'20120615 8:04:28 PM'),--*
(2,'20120615 8:04:33 PM');

;WITH x AS
(
  SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY time)
  FROM @x
)
SELECT x.value, x.[time]
FROM x LEFT OUTER JOIN x AS y
ON x.rn = y.rn + 1
AND x.value <> y.value
WHERE y.value IS NOT NULL;
```

Results:

```
value  time
-----  -----------------------
1      2012-06-15 20:03:43.000
2      2012-06-15 20:04:03.000
3      2012-06-15 20:04:13.000
2      2012-06-15 20:04:28.000
```

Comment: Wow that was fast.  Value increasing is OK.  I'll try it.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks @Aaron Bertrand.  On my data the second version took less than double the time of the first version, so the performance difference isn't too bad.

Comment: How to convert this query to also include an ID (new column) in the resulting output?

Comment: @ThinkCode you'll need to be more specific about what you want in that column. Right now I could put just about anything in a new column, but that wouldn't be very useful.

Comment: @Aaron : http://pastebin.com/LT0ygatC Instead of treating all rows for one ID, we now have 2 different IDs. Hope I made sense! Thank you

Comment: @ThinkCode Add PARTITION BY ID to the OVER() clause, then a sprinkling of ORDER BY on the outer query.

Comment: Tried your suggestions. http://pastebin.com/mMjzuyUT No go, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @ThinkCode Well, I'm not sure where `x.name` came from. Did you mean `x.ID`? Also, a specific error is usually more useful than "no go", for future reference. With an error message I could have spotted the error in the code without having to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry, it was x.ID not x.name. There is no error per say. In pastebin, I provided the output. It is repeating duplicate rows and not the intended result.

Comment: @ThinkCode Sorry, I can't follow your narrative and pastebin then. Please ask a separate question.

Comment: @AaronBertrand hi aaron if I don't want the last value means 2      2012-06-15 20:04:28.000 I don't want then

Answer (score 14):

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(value INT, [time] DATETIME)

INSERT @x VALUES
(0,'20120615 8:03:43 PM'),--
(1,'20120615 8:03:43 PM'),--*
(1,'20120615 8:03:48 PM'),--
(1,'20120615 8:03:53 PM'),--
(1,'20120615 8:03:58 PM'),--
(2,'20120615 8:04:03 PM'),--*
(2,'20120615 8:04:08 PM'),--
(3,'20120615 8:04:13 PM'),--*
(3,'20120615 8:04:18 PM'),--
(3,'20120615 8:04:23 PM'),--
(2,'20120615 8:04:28 PM'),--*
(2,'20120615 8:04:33 PM');


; with temp as
(
SELECT 
    value, [time],  lag(value,1,-1) over (order by [time] ) as lastValue
FROM    @x
) 
SELECT 
    [value],[time] 
FROM 
    temp 
WHERE value <> lastValue
```

Results:

```
value   time
---------------------------
0   2012-06-15 20:03:43.000
1   2012-06-15 20:03:43.000
2   2012-06-15 20:04:03.000
3   2012-06-15 20:04:13.000
2   2012-06-15 20:04:28.000
```

Comment: Neat, but worth mentioning this is only supported from SQL 2012 onward.

Comment: This was super fast! The query for previous versions worked 11 minutes and after that I had to cancel it.

Comment: LAG() and LEAD() are super-useful window functions - I use them on Presto DB and they save repeated scans through the same dataset - much faster

Comment: This was EXACTLY what I needed for one of my queries.  Thank you!!

Answer (score -1):

We can do this using sub queries also

```
SELECT sub1.value, sub1.time FROM 
  (SELECT *,rn,id FROM 
     (SELECT *,row_number() over (partition by value order by time) AS rn, row_number() over (order by time) AS id FROM x ) order by time) sub1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  (SELECT *,rn,id FROM 
     (SELECT *,row_number() over (partition by value order by time) AS rn, row_number() over (order by time) AS id FROM x ) order by time) sub2
  ON sub1.id = sub2.id + 1 
  WHERE sub1.rn - sub2.rn <> 1 OR sub2.rn IS NULL;
```

So,  I have compared the values of 2 rows if it changes then the difference of rn will be not equal to 1 otherwise rn value will increment by 1 so, I have picked all the rows whose difference with next row's rn value is not 1 and sub2.rn IS NULL is used for the first row because the join will occur from id = 2.