# How to find out when a column was changed in Oracle DB?

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

I want to be able to see when a specific column was changed.
To clarify, I don't want to see **when a row was changed.**  I was able to do that with ROWDEPENDENCIES and triggers with a timestamp. With ROWDEPENDICIES I can see when the whole row was modified last but I specifically want to find out when the a specific column was changed.

To clarify, I want the following table:

```
id   Name       Name_modified_on    Salary   Salary_modified_on
 1   Johnson    11.03.16 10:54:27   5000     11.03.16 10:51:27
```

How do I do that? Thanks.
PS: I'm running Oracle 11g.

Comment: What is `data1` and `data2`. Can you give example which will create/update the table you gave?

Comment: Do you have flashback turned on?

Comment: Basic strings or numbers, it could be anything. I'm going to edit my post to make it more clear, thanks. Flashback is turned off, but since I'm going to create a new database later on, I could turn it on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select rows where column value has changed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127461/select-rows-where-column-value-has-changed)

Comment: You could write a trigger comparing each column each time a row changes, and write your result to an audit table. is it what you want? This will be a _fancy_ trigger to write (for any given table). Otherwise if you want to keep the record for modification time, along with previous values, you have to write a full datawarehouse.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

1. Create a table:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE TEST
   (
     ID                  VARCHAR2(2000 BYTE),
     NAME                VARCHAR2(2000 BYTE),
     NAME_MODIFIED_ON    DATE                      DEFAULT sysdate,
     SALARY              NUMBER(10),
     SALARY_MODIFIED_ON  DATE                      DEFAULT sysdate
   );
   ```
2. Create a DB trigger:

   ```
   DECLARE
   /******************************************************************************
      NAME:       COLUMN_UPDATE_TRG
      PURPOSE:    

      REVISIONS:
      Ver        Date        Author           Description
      ---------  ----------  ---------------  ------------------------------------
      1.0        4.8.2016     Tomaz Kristan    1. Created this trigger.

      NOTES:

      Automatically available Auto Replace Keywords:
         Object Name:     COLUMN_UPDATE_TRG
         Sysdate:         4.8.2016
         Date and Time:   4.8.2016, 14:33:39, and 4.8.2016 14:33:39
         Username:         (set in TOAD Options, Proc Templates)
         Table Name:      Z_TEST (set in the "New PL/SQL Object" dialog)
         Trigger Options:  (set in the "New PL/SQL Object" dialog)
   ******************************************************************************/
   BEGIN

   IF UPDATING THEN

       IF ( :new.name is not null AND :new.name != :old.name ) THEN
            :new.name_modified_on := sysdate;
       END IF;   

       IF ( :new.salary is not null AND :new.salary != :old.salary ) THEN
            :new.salary_modified_on := sysdate;
       END IF;           

   END IF;

      EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
          -- Consider logging the error and then re-raise
          RAISE;
   END COLUMN_UPDATE_TRG;
   ```

Comment: I found your first if statement conditions rather helpful because thats what I was doing as well