# Select the oldest record of a certain group until it changes pattern, in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group

I am trying to get the oldest record for every status update/change in the following table.

### Table (status_updates) :

| id | entity_id | status | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 2 | Approved | 2022-02-10 |
| 6 | 2 | Approved | 2022-02-05 |
| 5 | 2 | Approved | 2022-02-04 |
| 4 | 2 | OnHold | 2022-02-04 |
| 3 | 2 | OnHold | 2022-02-03 |
| 2 | 2 | Approved | 2022-02-02 |
| 1 | 2 | Approved | 2022-02-01 |

### Result Needed :

| id | entity_id | status | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2 | Approved | 2022-02-04 |
| 3 | 2 | OnHold | 2022-02-03 |
| 1 | 2 | Approved | 2022-02-01 |

### Tried :

```sql
select
    `status`,
    `created_at`
from
    `status_updates`
left join
    (select
        `id`,
        row_number() over (partition by status_updates.entity_id, status_updates.status order by status_updates.created_at asc) as sequence
    from
        `status_updates`)
    as `oldest_history`
    on
        `oldest_history`.`id` = `shipper_credit_histories`.`id`
where `sequence` = 1
```

### Result Achived :

| id | entity_id | status | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2 | OnHold | 2022-02-03 |
| 1 | 2 | Approved | 2022-02-01 |

Comment: and what is your quetion?

Comment: You can refer to this post and try rewriting your query.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127461/select-rows-where-column-value-has-changed

Comment: Sure, let me try to elaborate the question.

Comment: Updated the problem statement, please check now @nbk

Comment: the problem occurs that rows are by definition unsorted, and you need to give it an order, which you don't have, for an algorithm all approved belong together as they have no column that tell them which belong together

Comment: Got your point. I am constantly getting stuck at the same point.
There should be a way to group the rows just until they change the pattern, in my case the status when the data is ordered by date.

Comment: I am open to change the schema of the table. Any Suggestions @nnichols

Comment: Added 'id' as a primary key to the table. Please check now @nnichols

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just using lag:

```
select s.*
from (
    select id, status<>coalesce(lag(status) over (partition by entity_id order by id),'') status_change
    from status_updates
) ids
join status_updates s using (id)
where status_change
```

Comment: If the runs are short and the table narrow, you may benefit from ditching the join and returning all required columns in the inner select. Worth checking with your full dataset.

Answer (score 0):

here are the queries:

```
create table status_updates
(entity_id integer,
status varchar(32),
date date
);

insert into status_updates values (2, 'Approved', '2022-02-05');
insert into status_updates values (2, 'Approved', '2022-02-04');
insert into status_updates values (2, 'On Hold', '2022-02-04');
insert into status_updates values (2, 'On Hold', '2022-02-03');
insert into status_updates values (2, 'Approved', '2022-02-02');
insert into status_updates values (2, 'Approved', '2022-02-01');

select b.*
from status_updates a
right join status_updates b 
on a.status=b.status and a.date=(b.date - interval 1 day) 
where a.entity_id is null;
```

or this query(if you prefer left join)

```
select a.*
from status_updates a
left join status_updates b
on a.status=b.status and a.date=(b.date + interval 1 day)
where b.entity_id is null;
```

in both you will see the expected result

Comment: Nice suggestion @"Alex G".

The interval between the dates is not fixed in my case, it is indeterministic.

Updated the Sample table above to show that. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

the second solution is almost the same, but join by id instead of date

```
create table status_updates
(id integer,
entity_id integer,
 status varchar(32),
 date date
);

insert into status_updates values (7, 2, 'Approved', '2022-02-10');
insert into status_updates values (6, 2, 'Approved', '2022-02-05');
insert into status_updates values (5, 2, 'Approved', '2022-02-04');
insert into status_updates values (4, 2, 'On Hold', '2022-02-04');
insert into status_updates values (3, 2, 'On Hold', '2022-02-03');
insert into status_updates values (2, 2, 'Approved', '2022-02-02');
insert into status_updates values (1, 2, 'Approved', '2022-02-01');

select a.*
from status_updates a
         left join status_updates b
                   on a.status=b.status and a.id=b.id + 1
where b.entity_id is null;
```

result is the same what you expected

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot rely on an auto-incrementing PK being contiguous as there are a number of situations that can lead to gaps. You can use a variation on this with another left join to check values between `a` and `b`.

Comment: sql returns exactly what is expected

Comment: Only until you introduce another entity_id or have a hole in your PK sequence - [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/y3EHeSkR)