# SQL: retrieve only the records whose value has changed with first row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Sorry, newbie here.

Similar to this here:  [SQL: retrieve only the records whose value has changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689912/sql-retrieve-only-the-records-whose-value-has-changed/43057905#43057905)

I wanted to find out how to also include the very first row?  The rows with the *'s?

```
ID  description    eaudittimestamp
--  -----------    -----------------------
777012  above       2017-03-27 10:09:59.330 *
777012  above       2017-03-27 10:09:58.550
777012  below       2017-03-27 10:26:03.560 *
777012  below       2017-03-27 10:36:02.423
777012  below       2017-03-27 10:37:15.250
777012  middle      2017-03-27 10:49:11.680 *
777012  middle      2017-03-27 10:49:18.870
777013      something       2017-03-27 11:49:18.870
777013      something       2017-03-27 12:49:18.870
777014      nodescription   2017-03-27 12:49:18.870
```

Apologies, I new to this.  let me rephrase.  I have a table, which has ID, description and timestamp.  Similar to an audit table.  How do I to find the rows (including the first) where the description has changed.

And how to exclude the ones that only have 1 row? i.e. 777013 and 777014?

Comment: you use like for the rate and get the max or min based on date or just do a top 1.

Comment: getting mixed up now.

Comment: yes sorry, learning to use the site. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
with ct as
(
    select Code, Date, Rate,
           row_number() over (partition by Code, Rate order by Code, Date) as rn
    from your_table
)
select Code, Date, Rate
from   ct
where  rn = 1
order by Code, Date;
```

**Update**

> ```
> declare @foo table(ID int,  description varchar(100),  eaudittimestamp datetime);
> insert into @foo values
> (777012, 'above', '2017-03-27 10:09:59.330'),
> (777012, 'above', '2017-03-27 10:09:58.550'),
> (777012, 'below', '2017-03-27 10:26:03.560'),
> (777012, 'below', '2017-03-27 10:36:02.423'),
> (777012, 'below', '2017-03-27 10:37:15.250'),
> (777012, 'middle', '2017-03-27 10:49:11.680'),
> (777012, 'middle', '2017-03-27 10:49:18.870'),
> (777013, 'something', '2017-03-27 11:49:18.870'),
> (777013, 'something', '2017-03-27 12:49:18.870'),
> (777014, 'nodescription', '2017-03-27 12:49:18.870');
>
> with ct as
> (
>     select ID, description, eaudittimestamp,
>            row_number() over (partition by ID, description order by eaudittimestamp) rn,
>            count(*) over (partition by ID) as ct
>     from   @foo
> )
> select ID, Description, eaudittimestamp
> from ct
> where rn = 1 and ct > 1;
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
>     ID | Description | eaudittimestamp    
> -----: | :---------- | :------------------
> 777012 | above       | 27/03/2017 10:09:58
> 777012 | below       | 27/03/2017 10:26:03
> 777012 | middle      | 27/03/2017 10:49:11
> 777013 | something   | 27/03/2017 11:49:18
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=9489c81751f6be7b9996cfa3647ea18c)*

Answer (score 1):

For the data you have provided, `row_number()` works:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id, description order by eaudittimestamp) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This returns one row per `id`/`description` pair.  The one with the lowest `eaudittimestamp`.  That appears to be what you want.

EDIT:

If you want to exclude the groups with one row, just use another window function:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id, description order by eaudittimestamp) as seqnum,
             min(description) over (partition by id) as min_d,
             max(description) over (partition by id) as max_d
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1 and min_d <> max_d;
```

Comment: thank you Gordon. what if there is multiples? I,e it should have returned 3 rows?

Comment: @Kayen this is the part where you look up [`row_number()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) and start trying to understand it for yourself. Go play on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com); I've created a [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b7c80/3) for you.

Comment: this works, but returns all rows where seq =1.  what if we only want to find the rows where there are changes?.

Comment: sorry not so clear.  I fix example.  with Gordon's code, 777013 would appear as it would be seq = 1.  how to make not include?

Comment: @Kay_e_n  . . . One method would be `count(distinct) over`, but I don't think that works in SQL Server 2008.  You can just look at the minimum and maximum values of `description` for each `id` and be sure that they are different.