# How to check changed columns in mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have table `user` where `id` = primary key, `lastchange` = int with `lastchange` data (in seconds). And i have frontend page with js script. Also all users placed in div like table by pages. So, items has user id and used changed timevalue in attributes.
I want to request all changed user ids in 1 request (1 http and 1 sql). They can be changed by other user on site.
How can i do this? I dont want check every user in page by timer, there is too many requests.

In my mind it looks like:

1. js do get request with list of users in page in json format `[{"id":1, "lastchange":123123},{"id":2, "lastchange":123123}...`
2. Php does request in mysql like `` SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` IN (1, 2, 3) AND `lastchange` NOT IN (123459, 123456, 123459); `` (this not works fine, there is no queue for `lastchange`, it checks all inside braces and result are wrong)
3. Php return only ids of different rows `[1, 15, 22]` etc. to js.
4. Js check every id separately in other request getting full info about user by id

I can check every user in php separately, but i want to know how can i do it with 1 `SQL` request

Sorry my bad English.

Comment: Maybe i can store every user change in other table (id, user, changetime) and check like ``select `user`, `changetime` from (where `user` in (select `id` from `changes` where `id` = $var))``

Comment: Once asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689912/sql-retrieve-only-the-records-whose-value-has-changed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL: retrieve only the records whose value has changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689912/sql-retrieve-only-the-records-whose-value-has-changed)

Comment: Or maybe, i can only send user ids and retrieve lastchanges from mysql, after check differents by JS and update user data

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to implement the solution differently as per the first comment.... but, if you want keep your current model the SQL you need would look something like:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE
(id = 1 AND lastchange <> 123123) OR
(id = 2 AND lastchange <> 123123) OR
...
```

This will keep the id's and the lastchange values that relate to each other being compared properly. It is pretty ugly SQL but not hard to generate in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my stupidness. I think i solve this.

1. Js request api with only user `id` in page
2. php response json like `id, lastchange`
3. js checking lastchange value and id in page
4. js request full data about changed user replaces old in page

Thx all for helping