# SQL: find records whose given field has different string values in consecutive days

Tags: sql, hiveql, presto

I have the following table and I need to find two consecutive days which have different status for the same person (No gap between days).

```
name    date           status
-------------------------------
John    2020-06-01     submitted
John    2020-06-02     pending
John    2020-06-03     approved
John    2020-06-04     approved
Amy     2020-06-02     pending
Amy     2020-06-03     pending
Amy     2020-06-04     pending
Dan     2020-06-02     submitted
Dan     2020-06-03     approved
Dan     2020-06-04     approved
Mary    2020-06-03     submitted
Mary    2020-06-04     pending
```

output should like below:

```
name    date           status
-------------------------------
John    2020-06-01     submitted
John    2020-06-02     pending
John    2020-06-03     approved
Dan     2020-06-02     submitted
Dan     2020-06-03     approved
Mary    2020-06-03     submitted
Mary    2020-06-04     pending
```

Currently I exported the table and wrote a python code to do that. However, I am wondering would it be possible to achieve that just using SQL? (I looked into [SQL: retrieve only the records whose value has changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689912/sql-retrieve-only-the-records-whose-value-has-changed) , but couldn't figure out how to make it work in my case since the `status` field is a string instead of number) Thanks!

Comment: Are there gaps between the dates?

Comment: @forpas no gap between days

Answer (score 0):

I'd self-join the table according to the name, consecutive days and different statuses:

```sql
SELECT a.name, a.date, a.status
FROM   mytable a
JOIN   mytable b ON a.name = b.name AND
                    a.date + INTERVAL '1' DAY = b.date AND
                    a.status <> b.status
```

Answer (score 0):

With [`LAG()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/window.html#lag) and [`LEAD()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/window.html#lead) window functions:

```
select t.name, t.date, t.status
from (
  select *,
    coalesce(lag(status) over (partition by name order by date), status) prev_status,
    coalesce(lead(status) over (partition by name order by date), status) next_status
  from tablename  
) t
where t.status <> t.prev_status or t.status <> t.next_status
order by t.name, t.date
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/245KSnkkEQGWR3TTwRiwxn/0).
Results:

```
| name | date       | status    |
| ---- | ---------- | --------- |
| Dan  | 2020-06-02 | submitted |
| Dan  | 2020-06-03 | approved  |
| John | 2020-06-01 | submitted |
| John | 2020-06-02 | pending   |
| John | 2020-06-03 | approved  |
| Mary | 2020-06-03 | submitted |
| Mary | 2020-06-04 | pending   |
```